# How to Left align and right align two different expression in the same text box in RDLC reports?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

Platform: RDLC report
Tool: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

In RDLC reports, is there a way to left and right align two different expression in the same textbox, as one of the text need to start from left side and the other from the right side of the textbox?

Comment: try textbox property -> alignment -> horizontal ->expression builder =iif(Fields!name.Value>1,"Left","Right")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following

```
in RDLC designer textbox property -> alignment -> 
horizontal ->
expression builder 
=iif(Fields!name.Value= "check","Left","Right")
```

Comment: Pay attention, the justification string is case sensitive! example : "Center" not "center" :D